# Sticker problem(Aptitude)

Tags: logic

Samuel had 23 stickers more than mary. Mary had 80 stickers more than Daniel. After Samuel and mary gave some stickers to daniel, they each had 120 stickers. How many stickers did Samuel have at first?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @paw88789 I tried considering them as the following equations: x=y+23; y=z+80; z; If x and y became 120 after giving some stickers to z. Here x depends on y and y depends on z right? If I assume y as 120 then my value of x will change(!=120)If I assume x as 120 y will be 97. I stuck in this loop.

Comment: Can you rewrite the equations in terms of a single variable? For example, can you write the number of stickers Samuel has $(x)$ in terms of $z$? How about $y$ in terms of $z$?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable hint. solved the problem by converting the equation into a single variable equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

x=y+23; 
y=z+80;
z=?
Each had 120 stickers after the distribution. Therefore total stickers involved in the problem is 120*3=360

x+y+z=360

(y+23)+(z+80)+z=360

((z+80)+23)+(z+80)+z=360

3z+183=360

z=59

Initially,

y=z+80=59+80=139;
x=y+23=139+23=162

Sam had 162, Mary had 139 and Daniel had 59 stickers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  "They each had $120$ stickers" means all three of them had $120$ stickers.  This gives you one more equation because you know the total number of stickers in circulation.  Now you have three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: Thank you for the hint it helped me a lot.